# face recognition database system in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, xml-parsing, yaml

I am working on face recognition. 
In order to store the trained faces which is better to use, xml or yaml file?
what makes difference among those two markup languages.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1308562/2863154)

Comment: possible duplicate of [YAML compared to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308536/yaml-compared-to-xml)