# Why yaml is popular? Is there anything else that does better.

Tags: ruby, json, yaml, yaml-cpp

I know that this is a very generic question, but I am sure this question will benefit most of the developers in making a choice of YAML over other markup languages stack overflow.

I came to know about YAML from one of my lab mates, who used to use it for all intermediate file operations in his project that we were working on. I asked him why only YAML? Why not JSON or XML? He said YAML is quite popular these days and that didn't seem quite a satisfying answer to me.

So asking here, why YAML over JSON and XML? In what scenarios does choosing YAML over any other language will be a good/bad choice.

Is there any other language that does better than YAML?

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308536/yaml-compared-to-xml

Comment: Note that neither JSON nor YAML are markup languages (XML is).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my question is not just comparing YAML over XML or JSON but to the whole gamut of markup like languages. Also I seek for a better markup language if possible.

Comment: I think a large part of it is YAML being the fault markup language for Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Markup languages help with formatting text. Templating languages help with programmatically writing text (think MadLibs). Data-serialization lanaguages help store data. YAML and JSON are for serialization. YAML has the benefit of being the most "human readable". In fact it's so human readable that some people use it as a markup language.

Comment: YAML is less redundant in marking up the data than JSON and even more than XML. That is why YAML more closer to human-readable format and so popular. Btw this question is also redundant.